# Meta Programming in rails

Tags: ruby-2.0

I have a class by name `Person` the methods are being added into name,description,nick_name
but these instance methods do have the same set of code

```
class Product
  def name
    p "this is the name of the product"
  end

  def description
    p "this is the descriptions of the product"
  end

  def nick_name
    p "this si the description of the nick name"
  end
end

class Person < Product
  %w(name description nick_name).map{|attr| attr.to_sym}.each do |definable_method|
    define_method definable_method do
      print "this is the #{definable_method} in the person"
      super
    end
  end  
end
```

```
 p1 = Person.new
 p1.name
```

Expected Result

```
 this is the name in the person
 this is the name of product
```

```
p1.description
```

Expected Result

```
  this is description in the person
  this is the descriptions of product
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```rb
class Product
  def name
    p "this is the name of the product"
  end

  def description
    p "this is the descriptions of the product"
  end

  def nick_name
    p "this si the description of the nick name"
  end
end

class Person < Product
  %w(name description nick_name).map{|attr| attr.to_sym}.each do |definable_method|
    define_method definable_method do
      print "this is the #{definable_method} in the person\n"
      super()
    end
  end
end

p1 = Person.new
p1.name
```